# Deleting a user login name from the start window in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-registry, login, start

When Logging in I accidentally started a new login. I never completed it but now when I login the second name appears in the list of login options. Now I must click on my login name to complete the login with the correct login name and password. I want to delete the other (false) name from the list of login names displayed on the start login window. After I have logged in the false name is not displayed in the User Account list.

I have looked in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-3893799831-3979369364-283611018-1001
```

but only my name is displayed in ProfilemagePath.

Comment: You can delete the user profile in Computer > Properties > Advanced systems settings.  Do that, restart and check.